# Tag filtering broken with JS error: initTagPrefs is not defined

Tags: bug, status-norepro, javascript, ignored-tags

Tag filtering just stopped working for me today on SO.  Was working fine on Friday but today all questions are showing up regardless of ignored tags.  Firebug shows this error in the console:

```
initTagPrefs is not defined
http://stackoverflow.com/questions
Line 669
```

Interesting tag highlighting is also not working.

I was surprised to see no other posts about it here.  Are others not affected?

Comment: This happened to me once a long time ago.  Sadly, I can't remember what caused it.  Maybe try clearing your cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a proxy is incorrectly caching files between you and us. Refresh your cache.

Comment: Is it just me, or does "Refresh your cache" more and more sound like "Did you try turning it off and on again?"

Comment: Maybe, but caches can cause a lot of strange bugs which can be solved by clearing the cache. It's an easy step for the user, but can prevent a lot of problems for the support guys.