# Phrase "Applet-Height-100" without "-"s causing page to break

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Check out this guys profile https://stackoverflow.com/users/391047/dave one of his answers is moved to the right. This popped up for me on the main stackoverflow page and the formatting became all screwed up. I can take a picture of it if you like.

**Dont mind my custom css lol**
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f2d8ef1437.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f2d8ef1437.jpg)

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/2172b58c10.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/2172b58c10.jpg)

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/55bda9f567.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/55bda9f567.jpg)

**EDIT:** Tested Jeffs link in chrome and still got the same error. Below is a screenshot in IE7
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/52337a9492.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/52337a9492.jpg)

I can just drop it, it doesn't matter to me. I'm just curious as to why this error is occuring. I had my collegue beside me check out the page and he got the same error, so its not just me.

Comment: Are you saying his profile page is broken, or some question that he answered is broken?

Comment: @mmyers, Both actually. His profile page shows the answers on the right side and I can't even see what his answer was. The screenshots above show what I am seeing. Dont mind the CSS

Comment: I'm not seeing this behavior (nor can I see any of the screenshots besides the first), but I'm starting to consider that maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144029/applet-height100-causes-vertical-scrollbar-in-ie-why-how-to-avoid/3336545#3336545 is the culprit, due to its title.

Comment: I turned the custom CSS off and it still renders that way. So it is not the CSS

Comment: @waiwai933, ...When I click the name "dave" it brings me to that profile page...

Comment: Now that your latter ones have loaded, judging that those are listed in the same order as vote sort, but located after the question I linked, I'm pretty sure that it is the culprit. As to what it is doing and how, though... not so sure.

Comment: Maybe there has to be a limit to how long the question title can be?

Comment: It's not a matter of question title length (which there already is a limit, anyway), I think it is the actual HTML tag. In your first screenshot, that's where it is breaking.

Comment: Anyone looking into this? Just reloaded daves page and its still there. @mmyers @Jeff Atwood ???

Comment: It shows up fine for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: @mmyers I'm using chrome. Are you able to click the link when it shows up? I tried it in IE and it shows the name but doesn't link anywhere

Comment: The link in the profile page works fine, if that's what you're asking. I'm using IE7.

Comment: Do you run Chrome with any Extensions? Disable them.

Comment: @Ladybug Killer ,Went to the page in incognito mode(no extensions), same thing.

Comment: Do you use a Beta version?

Comment: A colleague has the same problem? Do you have this problem only from your office? Does your company use a proxy?

Comment: @Ladybug Killer Nope, Chrome 5.0.375.99, IE 7.0.5730.13

Comment: I am currently going through a proxy. You think that could be causing this? I will check at home later today and post the results.

Comment: @Ladybug Killer ,So it rendered fine at home...I guess its something the proxy is doing with it...Wierd.

Comment: @Gage: Proxies can cause a lot of problems: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35221/tag-filtering-broken-with-js-error-inittagprefs-is-not-defined - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23030/problems-with-stack-overflow-when-using-linux-google-chrome

Comment: @Ladybug Killer, You want to post that as the answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Gage: Hmm, normally not, but if you wish so ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your case is probably the proxy of your company. Maybe they are caching old JavaScript libraries or they are filtering stuff, whatever.

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35221/tag-filtering-broken-with-js-error-inittagprefs-is-not-defined) for other examples of [this problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23030/problems-with-stack-overflow-when-using-linux-google-chrome).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with the question.

You can view it here in a live question page list:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=applet&sort=active